# PHP Connect to MySQL: When to create connection

Tags: php, mysql

As I learn more about PHP and MySQL, I become quite confused about when to create a connection to the server. I wonder whether I have to create a new connection everytime I do a new query. For example, do I need to create two connections if I want to update some data, using the codes below? Can someone explain the mechanism to me? Thanks!

```php
$db_con2=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$db_con=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

if($db_con){

    some operations omitted

    $stmt = $db_con2->prepare("");
    $stmt->bind_param();
    $stmt->execute();   
}

mysqli_close($db_con2);
mysqli_close($db_con);
```

Comment: kinda - just create a connection file that has the `new .. ` stuff in, then just require/include that at the top of any file that uses mysql, then include a closing file to close connections, and likewise just call that at the bottom of your scripts/pages that uses that connection

Comment: Unless you want to use a different DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD or DB_NAME you don't need to have multiple connections.

Comment: Why not try that out and see what happens? Just out of curiosity: what gives you the idea this could ever be neccessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use a single connection for different databases, by using a fully-qualified table identifier, i.e.: `database1.table1`
2. It is not recommended to create more connections than needed (usually one), since it generates more overhead and there is also an upper cap on the number of parallel connections (there can be multiple requests x multiple connections).
3. The only thing you cannot do on a single connection in MySQL afaik is run two cursors in parallel. This means, if query1 is a select, you have to fetch the full recordset of query1 before issuing query2. You cannot issue query2 (further selects or updates) while iterating over the results of query1. This is only true if you use unbuffered queries. For buffered queries, PHP is transparently reading and caching every recordset in full for you. You might care about this if you need unbuffered queries; for further reading: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: Good write up about buffered queries

Answer (score 2):

Think of the connection as the variable. `$db_con` as your connection and you establish this at the start of every new script, (using a class or an included file in your script) , and then you can run any SQL queries you need on that same variable.

You do **not** need to manually close the MySQLi connection, because this is automatically closed when the end of the script is reached. So putting `$db_con->close()` (*this is the correct syntax*) on the last lines of your script is not needed.

A typical script would have an included class or file that has the connection data; at the top of the script, then this is used throughout the script and all details are forgotten at the end of the script automatically.

Also please do not get confused with **Procedural** and **Object Orientated** interactions. You are using Object Orientated currently, but your `mysqli_close()` function call is a *Procedural* call and these two methods are not interactive with each other.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create a different file for the connection object, and use it wherever required by including this file, in the file you want the connection object in, if you are pretty sure you are using the same HOST, DB and its tables throughout your Project.

This way you can save your LOC (Line Of Code) thus making it Optimal, which will also save your time and unwanted tedious work.

Also you do not need to close the connection everytime. The following is optional :

```
mysqli_close(CONNECTION_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please modify your connection according to this:**

```
$mysqli_c1 = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database1); 
$mysqli_c2 = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database2);
```

Using database1:

```
$mysqli_c1->query('select * from tablename');
```

Using database2:

```
$mysqli_c2->query('select * from tablename');
```

According to your code:

```
if($mysqli_c1->connect_errno){
   //Error handle code here
}else{
   //success code here
}
```

Comment: `Mysql_` functions should not be used.

Comment: that are the example if we need want to use.

Comment: Main part is mysql_query.

Comment: The Original Poster is using (mostly) Object Orientated programming, but your examples are Procedural Programming style.

Comment: Ok so what i have to do there?

Comment: Convert the procedural `mysql_` queries into Object Orientated `$mysqli->` queries `:-)`

Comment: Awesome. That's much better `:-)`